# Error inflating class ImageButton during runtime but Android Studio shows no errors and compiles flawlessly

Tags: android, android-layout

Application crashes with the following exception:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #185: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class ImageButton
```

But Android Studio shows no layout errors, layout preview of the file that is responsible for the crash is properly rendered and the application can be compiled and run.

Crashing `ImageButton`:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/kasablok_pager_btn_left"
    android:layout_width="74dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_24dp"
    android:rotation="180"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

The source drawable exists and is click-through to the file. There are no errors or warnings in the preview window to indicate a possible problem.
`vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` is also properly set in my `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer**: the `ic_chevron_right_black_24dp.xml` file was located in the specific `res/drawable-v24` folder instead of the common `res/drawable`. This way the `id` was only available on API 24+. Moving the file into the latter folder did solve the problem. My phone ran Android **M** (API 23) and that's why it crashed. The `ic_chevron_right_black_24dp` `id` could not be found.

**How did the file end up in the wrong directory without my knowledge?**
I copied the `ic_chevron_right_black_24dp.xml` file over from another project. What I did was to paste the file into the `drawable` resource directory while viewing the project as `Android` (the top left dropdown that allows you to choose how to represent your project in the left navigation panel). Android studio somehow decided to put the file into the specific `drawable-v24` instead of the general `drawable` folder.

**Why didn't Android Studio show any errors and why was the preview properly inflated?**
The layout preview was properly inflated because the preview and also the `compileSdkVersion` was set to `android-P`. This way the preview was rendered as if it was on `android-P` API, where the resource existed.

**How to tackle `InflateException` in your application?**
When you see an `InflateException`, this exception itself doesn't provide any usable information about your problem. It can be caused by a variety of different independent things. You must look deeper. `InflateException` is not the cause - it is the effect caused by something else.

In my case the whole stack trace looked like this:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #185: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class ImageButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2335)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1423)
    .....

 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class ImageButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
    .....
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070070
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1364)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:328)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:193)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:58)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:78)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:68)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:201)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:121)
```

That's more usable. The trace shows that the `InflateException` was triggered by a `Resources$NotFoundException` and this was the real culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error, move the file(*Image*) from `/res/drawable-v24` to the general folder `/res/drawable`, this is folder for any versions, and handle it with `app:src` in the layout code XML.